# adding new file type to ultisnips

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I am trying to add for the cuda (.cu) files. The basic objective is to first make all c,cpp snippets available for the cu files and then add additional support. The first thing I did to test is to set the filetype inside vim

`set ft:cpp.c`

and this works. Then I tried to go to the `vim-snippets/snippets` and `vim-snippets/UltiSnips` and tried to copy the cpp.snippets file to cu.snippets. But this is not working (not working as in --the snippets are not detected--) . I have also added

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cu set ft=cuda
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cuh set ft=cuda
```

in my .vimrc. Even after this it is not working.

I also checked the `UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`. It is pointing to `Ultisnips`.

I also tried creating a cu.snippets which just tries to extend cpp (nothing else). This is also not working.

As a side question: As far I understand https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets has two folders with snippets. `snippets/*` for the snipmate based ones and `UltiSnips/*` for the ultisnips based ones. However the `inc` snippet is only provided on the c.snippets in snippets directory (not in ultisnips). But strangely `inc` works on `c` files for me. I am positive that I am not using snipmate. How could this happen? Am I missing something. or is it that ultisnips can understand both formats?

Answer (score 1):

Ultisnips uses Vim's filetype detection system. So to see what filetype Vim thinks you have use the `:set filetype?` command.

If that's incorrect, you can try

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.cu setfiletype cuda
```

Also, I used Vundle, and I used `call vundle#rc()`, but I needed to change that to `call vundle#begin()` and `call vundle#end()`

Answer (score 0):

I think, some plugin in your plugins list conflicts with your custom filetype detection config. Just faced with the same issue (tried to declare custom filetype for Jest typescript tests for react). My filetype settings overrides by `peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript` plugin.

So you should to switch off some of yor installed `cpp` plugins for detect culprit.